# I cannot get the background image to drop below text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```
<td class="navStyle">
         @Html.ActionLink(@Resources.Resources.Menu_Quote,"Index",
                           "Quote", new { area = "" }, 
         new {@class = "navStyleImage_requestQuote navStyle" })
</td>
```

CSS

```
.navStyle {
    width:auto;
    height:40px;
    padding:0px 5px 0px 5px;
    font-size:12pt;
    color:#ceeff3;
    text-decoration:none;
    font-family:"Trebuchet MS", Helvetica, sans-serif;
    vertical-align:top; 
}

a.navStyleImage_requestQuote:hover {
    background-image:url("images/Inovir_Navigation_GetAQuote.png");
    background-position:bottom;
    background-size:100%;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    text-decoration:none;
}
```

I cannot get my background image to drop below the text, when I try to push it pass the text it disappears

Comment: Post the rendered HTML, not whatever `@Html.ActionLink` is

Comment: what type of coding this is? is that HTML only?

Answer (score 0):

In your CSS, set the z-index property

```
.backelement {
     z-index:1;
}

.frontelement {
     z-index:2;
}
```

The element with the higher stack index is in front of the element with the lower stack index.